# C++ Troubles allocating matrix with only cols known and unknown rows

Tags: c++, c, vector, matrix, malloc

I've a doubt.

I 've a matrix which I know that will have 3 columns, but the number of rows will be defined in the constructor of the class that store the matrix. Then I declare the variable as

```
int * ColorsYUV[3];
```

But when I tried to allocate it using malloc:

```
ColorsYUV = (int *) malloc(sizeof(T) * 8 * sizeof(int) * 3);
```

I get this error:

```
incompatible types in assignment of ‘int*’ to ‘int* [3]’
```

How can I solve that problem. The only idea that I realize is using a simple vector and access to it adding a "for" loop from 0 to 2, but, If it's possible I prefer an access like a matrix.

```
ColorsYUV[i][0]...
ColorsYUV[i][1]...
ColorsYUV[i][2]...
```

I hope I  explained my self...
Thanks in advance.

Comment: is it C++ or C? Cause they are rather different, so please adjust your tags.

Comment: I'm using C++ but I tought that pointers rule equal in both C & C++. I'm newbie I've only 2 weeks in C++ please dont be tough. I think that I overcome the troubles with the other answer, but thanks for the time that you took reading my problem.

Comment: @Bardo91 Pointers are pretty much the same in both languages, but the C++ solution for this sort of problem doesn't use pointers; the C solution does.  (What you have written is basically C.  One would never write it in C++.)

Comment: Oh, I didn't know it. I believe that it is always better to allocate like C allocation even in C++. Thanks again. I'll check my whole code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, as ogni42 says, you really should use
`std::vector<std::array<int, 3>>`; if you don't have C++11,
then use `boost::array` instead of `std::array`.  Otherwise, if
you're really using C instead of C++:

```
int* ColorsYUV[3];
```

declares an array of three pointers.  What you want is:

```
int (*ColorsYUV)[3];
```

which is a pointer to an array of three.

Then, I don't understand your malloc: where does `sizeof(T)`
come into it:  If you want to allocate an 8 by 3 matrix:

```
ColorsYUV = (int (*)[3])malloc( 8 * 3 * sizeof(int) );
```

Note that you've had to duplicate the type of the pointer in the
cast; `ColorsYUV` is *not* an `int*`, so casting the return
value of `malloc` to `int*` is not going to work.  (Of course,
if you're using C, you can just do what everyone else does, and
drop the cast completely.  C allows an implicit conversion of
`void*` to any object pointer type.)

Comment: +1 for demarcating between array of pointer and pointer to an array of three!

Comment: Oh srry I was using a template in the class. T can be int, float or double. Thanks you for the answer and also thanks ogni42. I'm so pleased. Now I think that I understand better that pointers

Answer (score 0):

First of all: If it is C++ consider using a `std::vector<array<int, 3>>`. You will get the array access `[][]` plus memory management for free.

If you want to fix you problem while staying with C-style, you need to fix the cast to the right type

Comment: If he's sticking to C, he'll have to fix the declaration of `ColorsYUV` too.  At present, it's an array (which means that you cannot assign to it, nor cast a pointer to it).  But of course, this is the sort of thing which shows _why_ one should switch to C++.

Answer (score 0):

First declare pointer array (columns)

```
 int (*ColorsYUV)[3];
```

Then allocate memory using 'for' loop. It is used as one pointer can be pointed to a memory address at a time, not the whole array. Assuming number of rows = 8, So

```
  int no_of_rows = 8; //value set as an example
  for (i=0;i<3;i++)
  {
     ColorsYUV[i] = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * no_of_rows);
  }
```

Hopefully you wont get errors now.